# Varchar measure in Olap Cube

Tags: olap, ssas, olap-cube, measure

All the measures should be necessarily numerical? what about a varchar measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have real varchar measures. You can however create a calculated measure that has some varchar value assigned / calculated, but that is not what you want I believe.

What you can do is create a fact dimension (degenerate dimension) and use that field either as an attribute hierarchy or as a member property.

HTH,
Hrvoje